# Contextual selectors

Tags: css

could anyone  tell me please, how would the contextual selector for "button3" looked like?

```
<div class="LeftPanel">
  <div class="MenuBar">
    <a  href="#">Akvárium</a>
    <a  href="#">Rybičky</a>
    <a  class="button3" href="#">Rostliny</a>
    <a  href="#">odkazy</a>
  </div>
```

I solved this problem by making another div element like this:

```
<div class="LeftPanel">
  <div class="MenuBar">
    <a  href="#">Akvárium</a>
    <a  href="#">Rybičky</a>
   <div class"xxxx"> <a  class="button3" href="#">Rostliny</a> </div>
    <a  href="#">odkazy</a>
  </div>
```

Then the contextual selector looks like this: div.MenuBar div.xxxx a:before{}
Doesn't exist better way how to do it guys?

Thank you for every help.

Comment: `.MenuBar > a.button3:before {...}` or `.MenuBar > a:nth-of-type(3):before {...}`

Comment: That's it :) Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I put it as an answer. Now you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pick up this element you can do it by many ways:

1. `.MenuBar > a.button3:before {...}`
2. `.MenuBar > a:nth-of-type(3):before {...}`
3. `.MenuBar > a:nth-child(3):before {...}`
4. `.MenuBar > a[class="button3"]:before {...}`

Generally it depends on conditions and context.

Comment: Got it. I Am quit new in this stuff and your answer helped me a lot, so thank you ;)